# android alarmmanager starting once a month

Tags: android, timer, repeat, alarmmanager, timertask

I want the alarmManager to perform a task every 5th of the month at 3pm. How would I do that?

- first start depends on when the user installs the app. Okay I can do some math calculating how many ms it takes to the next 5th of the month, but I hope there is an easier way
- the repeat option gives me a real headache. I only can set one fixed intervall. but the time between two month is not fixed since sometimes I have 30, sometimes 31 days (not to mention Feb).

How would I do this best?

Regards,
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much simpler, have a look at the Date class:
<strike>http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html</strike>

And Try something like, Pseudo:

```
// This month 5th
Date date = new Date();
date.setDay(5);
// Next month the 5th
Date nextDate = new Date();
nextDate.setDay(5);
nextDate.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
```

You would have issues when you come to end of the year, but it's less issues than you have at the moment.

There are other Date API's and some will fix the year problem for you. Just have a look around.

*EDIT*

Just noticed that's deprecated use Calendar:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setField(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
// Next month the 5th
Calendar nextDate = new = Calendar.getInstance();
nextDate.setField(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
nextDate.setField(Calendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR, date.getField(Calendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR)+1); // issues in december
```

Comment: `Calendar` is a better choice than `Date`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was editing as you were commenting :-) Normally use DateMidnight() in Java as it has plus(duration); to account for months and years, any recommendations?

Comment: okay for the very first start date that shall do. Now I only need the repeating bit.

Comment: see where I have set up nextDate var, you would only set up your next alarm when the last one has been triggered. Therefore keep using nextDate each time you set up the next month's alarm but just watch out / check for December and increment the year